"Divider" UI Element in Android Studio
This may seem simple but I'm having a hard time, nonetheless. (App Dev student here) I just want to change the colour of the "divider" widget in Android Studio.
I tried using Blackbox for an explanation, but it didn't help. Does anyone know a way?

You need to be more specific.  What "divider" widget?  Android has no such concept.  Possibly a library you're using on top of it does, but you don't have one tagged.

I went into Android Studio and it's labelled as a "horizontal divider" and there's a vertical one too, I just want to change their colour.

There is no such thing as a "divider" in standard android.  You generally divide elements either with margin or by putting in a view with a background.  You may be using some library that introduces one, but if so you'd need to specify which
